# Display dropdown attribute on order page at backend

Tags: backend

How to display drop down attribute on order page at back end?
Tried editing the file grid.php.. it is diplaying the ID of a dropdown attribute but i want a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Grid.php file, within the `_prepareColumns()` method:

```
$options = array( 
    5 => 'Winter', 
    6 => 'Summer', 
    7 => 'Spring'
);
$this->addColumn('your_column',
    array(
        'header'=> $this->__('Seasons'),
        'width' => '5%',
        'index' => 'seasons',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'options'   => $options
    )
);
```

Comment: Nothing changed, besides its not even displaying the ID

Comment: Have you substituted your column name into the `your_index` section? (The column name in the table that you're using for this grid)

Comment: Here is what im using 
$this->addColumn('seasons', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Seasons'),
            'width'     => '80',
   'index'     => 'seasons',
   'type'  => 'options',
         'options'   => $options
        
        )
  );
    $options = array(
      5 => 'Winter',
      6 => 'Summer',
      7 => 'Spring',
 );

Comment: Are you defining the options array prior to calling the `$this->addColumn` method?

Comment: Nopes.. im new to magento so can u please ellaborate abit :)

Comment: basically i want my dropdown attr 'seasons' should display its value in front of every product

Comment: Okay, well you need to define the `$options` array above the call for `$this->addColumn`, I've updated my answer to indicate this.

Comment: Great :) Don't forget to mark as the chosen answer when you can.

Comment: there is another issue.. i want seasons to pull the value dynamically, not like here we have assigned the value to the id.. what if i delete current season and add new ? anything u can come up with ?